# Responsive 4:3 image crop within columns

Tags: html, css

I've created a three-column layout using Flexbox and each column has a width of 31.3%. Then, each column contains an image that occupies 100% of its column's width. Since there are no fixed widths, I'm struggling to crop and resize the images at a 4:3 aspect ratio.

This is my structure:

```
<div id="events-cont">
  <div class="events-row">
    <div class="event-card">
      <div class="event-card-img">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=600&h=300" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="event-card-info">
        <h1>Event title</h1>
        <h2>Event date</h2>
        <h2>Event venue</h2>
        <p>
          Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
          <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
        </p>
        <div class="button-cont">
          <a class="button blue-button" href="#">Buy Tickets</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card">
      <div class="event-card-img">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=600&h=300" /></a>
        <div class="series-caption">Series title</div>
      </div>
      <div class="event-card-info">
        <h1>Event title</h1>
        <h2>Event date</h2>
        <h2>Event venue</h2>
        <p>
          Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
          <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-card">
      <div class="event-card-img">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=600&h=300" /></a>
        <div class="series-caption">Series title</div>
      </div>
      <div class="event-card-info">
        <h1>Event title</h1>
        <h2>Event date</h2>
        <h2>Event venue</h2>
        <p>
          Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
          <a href="#">Learn More <span class="chevron right"></span></a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.events-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.events-row .event-card {
  background-color: #666;
  flex-basis: 31.3%;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 295px;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-img .series-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: black;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info h2 {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info p {
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info p a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info .button-cont {
  text-align: center;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info .button-cont .button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/NbOwaV.

Comment: Post your CSS in your question as well

Comment: @j08691 Just added!

Comment: Did you figure things out, or are you still wanting help with this? 
Keeping the image at a 4:3 ratio, do you plan on it shrinking and growing to fit the columns they're in then? You have the `height: 295px` for the image section. How do you want the image to look when width is smaller than the height for the container?

Comment: @TrevorNestman Yes, I still need help with this. The 295 is just a placeholder. Basically, I want the image to always occupy 100% of its container's width (edge-to-edge), while the height adjusts automatically to stay at 4:3. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jQuery solution: http://codepen.io/blainerw/pen/XNxEpd

The markup (HTML) is the same.

The CSS is a little different. I removed the heights from `.events-row .event-card .event-card-img` and `.events-row .event-card .event-card-img img`.

```
.events-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.events-row .event-card {
  background-color: #666;
  flex-basis: 31.3%;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-img {
  position: relative;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-img .series-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: black;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info h2 {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info p {
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info p a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info .button-cont {
  text-align: center;
}

.events-row .event-card .event-card-info .button-cont .button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

And then used a jQuery function to check the width of the column and add the appropriate height to the image.

```
function calcHeight() {

  var heightCalc = $('.event-card').width() * 0.75;

  $('.events-row .event-card .event-card-img img').height(heightCalc);

}

$(document).ready(function(){

  calcHeight();

});

$(window).resize(function() {

  calcHeight();

});
```

Comment: I had a feeling I might need to use jQuery. Thanks for this!